# How to add Header view for the PagedSliverList UI in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, listview

Hello In my Flutter application, I am using PagedSliverList widget to display the List data which is coming from the rest api response and its completely working fine.

But, I have to add some custom view at the top of this list, we can say the Header view for the PagedSliverList widget.

I am new to Flutter and I have googled about it but could not get anything specific to it. Is there any way to do it?

I need Scrollable header with SliverPersistentHeader widget.